# How to integrate Google API 2.1 into Android 2.1

Tags: android

I have created one Application which is developed on android 2.1.
I wanted to use Google maps in my Application that is why I used Google 
APIs 2.1 and it is also working properly.
But now I want to integrate Google API 2.1 into my Application developed in 2.1
can any one tel me how to do this.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I can not understand your problem.

Comment: Don't get your point! If you are going to use Google map you need to use Google API.

Answer (score 1):

The Google APIs include everything in the Android 2.1 APIs including maps (and some other things). If you are using Google APIs, you don't need to include anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand AVD. 
Google API 2.1 = Android API 2.1 + Google API.

AVD setting is just for compiling the code and emulator. Whatever you develop with Google 2.1 target SDK, will runs on actual 2.1 devices, with fragmentation in mind.